# AWS Beanstalk - How to print out stuff in application code and view it in deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am currently deploying a Flask app to AWS Beanstalk, and I am trying to log out some stuff in the application (print), but I am not sure how to view it within Beanstalk, do guide me along, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The print should be in `/var/log/web.output.log`. However, they can show up with a delay. Thus, I found that its easier to hook up into `gunicorn` logger from flask which update `web.output.log` in real time.

Below is sample `application.py` that you can test it out and see how to set it up:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, Blueprint
from flask_restful import Api

from datetime import datetime

import logging

application = Flask(__name__)

@application.route("/")
def hello():

    current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")

    print(f"print from the app {current_time}")
    
    application.logger.info(f"info from hello {current_time}")
    application.logger.error(f"error from hello {current_time}")
    
    return "<h1 style='color:blue'>Hello There!</h1>"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run()
else:
    gunicorn_logger = logging.getLogger('gunicorn.error')
    application.logger.handlers = gunicorn_logger.handlers
    application.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

Comment: thank you so much for answering! can i ask why the logger is placed in the else statement? sorry im new to using elastic beanstalk and new to deployment in general! also, can i ask, is there any additional configuration i would have to make to set up gunicorn in my application? or is it already handled for by elastic beanstalk?

Comment: @jason So that it only runs when the file is not executed directly. Please have a look [here](https://trstringer.com/logging-flask-gunicorn-the-manageable-way/) as the setup is mostly based on this.

Comment: oh i see! when running the WSGI gunicorn, the application file is not executed directly, hence it would run through the logger. thank you so much for your explanation! really appreciate it. can i ask, what are the steps to setting up gunicorn with elastic beanstalk? or would it be automatically set up by eb, and we dont have to handle for it at all? (apart from the code you gave me for logging)

Comment: @jason On EB platforms based on Amazon Linux 2, `gunicorn` works out of the box.